# Instagram API, get more than 20 pictures from my OWN account

Tags: api, curl, sdk, instagram, feed

Sandbox mode is now limited to 20 media calls. So when attempting to submit the app for review, choosing the option of

I want to display my Instagram posts on my website
prompts this response:

You do not need to submit for review for this use case. If you are a developer and you want to display Instagram content on your website, then you do not need to submit your app for review. By using a client in sandbox mode, you can still access the last 20 media of any sandbox user that grants you permission.

So it would appear that my Instagram Client is now trapped at only 20 media calls at a time, and we can't seem to find a solution.

Anyone was able to get more than the last 20 pictures? Is instagram Api really this shit? Cant believe this

btw: theres alot of questions about this here, buts they are all outdated, since they changed their politics in 2016, im looking for a working solution.

Thanks in advance!